# convert a numbers in a data.frame in significance stars in R

Tags: r, function

I am looking for a function or a library to convert a number in the significance stars in a data.frame.

Using the function *add.significance.stars()* of [pander package](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/pander/docs/add.significance.stars) i can convert numbers in significance stars. I wish to build a function in order to convert the number is a data.frame in   significance stars. Example

```
mydata <-  data.frame("Su1"=c(1,1,0.0004),"Su2"=c(NA,1,0.03),"Su3"=c(NA,NA,0.007))
rownames(mydata) <- c("Su2","Su3","Su4")


mydata
       Su1  Su2   Su3
Su2 1.0000   NA    NA
Su3 1.0000 1.0000   NA
Su4 0.0004 0.03 0.007
```

with *add.significance.stars()*  i wish a table like:

```
mydata
           Su1  Su2   Su3
    Su2 "_1.0000_"   NA    NA
    Su3 "_1.0000_" "_1.0000_"    NA
    Su4 "_0.0004_ * * *" "_0.03_ *" "_0.007_ * *"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sapply` loses the row.names, but you can put them back

```
mystars = sapply(mydata, add.significance.stars)
rownames(mystars) = rownames(mydata)

mystars
#     Su1             Su2        Su3          
# Su2 "_1_"           "_NA_NA"   "_NA_NA"     
# Su3 "_1_"           "_1_"      "_NA_NA"     
# Su4 "_4e-04_ * * *" "_0.03_ *" "_0.007_ * *"
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way that doesn't lose the row names and that keeps it as a data frame instead of converting it to a matrix (I found the trick with `[]` [here](http://collectedrcode.tumblr.com/post/47778481668/keep-the-rownames-df)):

```
mydata[] <- sapply(mydata, add.significance.stars)
mydata
#               Su1      Su2         Su3
# Su2           _1_   _NA_NA      _NA_NA
# Su3           _1_      _1_      _NA_NA
# Su4 _4e-04_ * * * _0.03_ * _0.007_ * *
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` to iterate trough all cells of a `data.frame` via `MARGIN = c(1,2)`:

```
> apply(mydata, c(1, 2), add.significance.stars)
    Su1             Su2        Su3          
Su2 "_1_"           "_NA_NA"   "_NA_NA"     
Su3 "_1_"           "_1_"      "_NA_NA"     
Su4 "_4e-04_ * * *" "_0.03_ *" "_0.007_ * *"
```

To eliminate the `NA` issue, please submit a [ticket on GH](https://github.com/rapporter/pander/issues).